# Java Applet + MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, applet, localhost

I've got applet and database in MySQL (results collection from applet). 
What should I put on localhost (of course except of java class) to save the results to database? When I do it in Netbeans, everything works!

Comment: It sounds like the problem is 'paths and permissions'.  Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

Comment: It means that I have to put there only a class? What's with connector j jar file?

Comment: there is "0" in console

Comment: Enable Java console from control panel and show us an error if any.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code of connection:

```
    public void connection() {
    try{
        String name = login.getText();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/nowa", "root", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '" + name + "'");

        while (rs.next()) {
            lastName = rs.getString("id");

            remove(panel2);
            add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            revalidate();
            repaint(); 
        }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        error.setText("Wrong login");
    }
}
```

In NetBeans it works. When I use it on localhost in html file , applet shows the exception :/ I put only the classes of applet on localhost - enough?